# Parse/Scrape from Multiple Pages using XMLHTTP in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

The code below only scrapes/parses one page of data (50 results) into excel however, I would like it to scrape multiple pages (500 results) - please help. (Base64Encode was taken from a different source - I don't take credit for it)

```
`Function GetData() As Boolean
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 Dim objHTTP As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP

 Dim strURL As String
 Dim strUserName As String
 Dim strPassword As String


 Sheet1.Range("A2:R2000") = ""

 Sheet1.Activate

 strUserName = "User"
 strPassword = "Password"

 For i = 1 To UBound(MyArray)

 strURL = "https://.ngx.com/ngxcs/indexPrice.xml" 
 objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
 objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & Base64Encode(strUserName & ":" & strPassword)
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Host", "secure.example.com"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text"

objHTTP.send "Nothing"

While objHTTP.readyState <> 4
   DoEvents
Wend

Dim strResponseReceived As String

strResponseReceived = objHTTP.responseText
Debug.Print objHTTP.responseText
MsgBox strResponseReceived


Dim xDoc As DOMDocument
Set xDoc = New DOMDocument

xDoc.LoadXML objHTTP.responseText`
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Rest of Code that outputs it into excel

Thanks for the Help!

Comment: While your code has been redacted to the point of inoperablity (see the strURL  string concatenation) you may find your answer in the [setTimeOuts method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760403(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @Jeeped There i made some minor changes - i still cant figure it out. Please give me some tips - im still very beginner

Comment: "The readystate doesn't seem to be working" - exactly what do you see which makes you think that?

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with the readystate, but with the number of results displayed per page. You probably only see the first page, which has 50 results. Try if there are settings to change that number, or see if there is any reference to it in the URL. Otherwise you might want to make a loop that loops through the page numbers in your URL.

Comment: God guys take it easy on me - im still a beginner